# Apache configuration problems? Why Perl scripts can't be executed - browser download scripts

Tags: 12.04, apache2, perl, cgi

I've got wrong apache configuration. My script don't want to be executed and browser trying to download it as a file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName president.com

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi/

<Directory /var/www/cgi/>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

1. Scripts are own by `www-data:www-data` with rights `755` and can be
   executed (`+x`).
2. Shebang e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl`.
3. Error log is **empty**.

Comment: @Rinzwind I replace that part and the DocumentRoot section, but is doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I remove all `Require all granted` (it's only for Apacvhe 2.4+) and paste:

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Also i move `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl` to DocumentRoot directory description

Comment: Nice one! don't forget to accept in a few hours;have an upvote to start with :)